# PC does not show POST screen on graphics card

Tags: windows-7, linux, graphics-card, gpu, console

I have had this issue recently where I power on my PC and it displays nothing, first I didn't thought much about it, but then the display shows up when it reaches to Windows logo and loading sign.

I have dual booted my system with fedora as 2nd one due to re-installation of Windows 10 over Linux, I had to change my OS but I couldn't because monitor doesn't show up on OS selection screen. I tried to check what was wrong so I pulled out my GPU and used integrated graphics and it booted fine from POST to selection screen to Windows welcome screen, but when I re inserted my GPU, this happened again.

I, sometimes, try to select the OS by keys randomly and hopes it loads fedora. So, I once checked on it too and system doesn't show anything until I reach its account's selection screen, I even tried to run another tth on console, but the monitor goes blank as soon as I switch to a console mode and when I switch back to the GUI one it starts to show up.

**Configuration**

- OS

  1. Windows 10
  2. Fedora 26
- Motherboard: ASUS H97M-E
- GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 650Ti Boost

**Update:**
I set Graphics configuration to force use PCI-E and enabled dual monitor display, but I get same results and with the card inserted I tried to use integrated port and using the card's port, which said no display. I tried with built-in HDMI port and ran both OS which gave fine results, I also read somewhere that it could be due to cable getting old, but I highly doubt it as I get right results when using integrated port, could it be due to driver with NVIDIA for Linux?

Comment: Does the Nvidia show POST screen? Try using another monitor

Comment: Try setting the Nvidia card as standard in the advanced settings of your BIOS instead of the integrated.

Comment: @RACING121 no that's the problem I can't get into BIOS

Comment: @ateebahmed Try another monitor and see if it POSTS there

Comment: @RACING121 well bad luck, I don't have another monitor, and I started my PC after a while, and after selecting fedora on first startup, it showed POST on restart and I got into it and checked the settings of Graphics card which were set to Auto I thought of forcing it to use the card but I didn't and then exited, but after booting into Fedora, the display was set to 640x480 and there weren't any more selections so I tried to go into different tth but it froze there so I had to restart and now I can't go into fedora because when I select it, it goes blank and I have to restart again.